# Replace values of elements in a list on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a random list which is;

**newList = [2, 44, 28, 32, 46, 31]**

I have a random value which has to be in this way;

**{1:8, 2:7, 3:6, 4:5, 5:4, 6:3, 7:2, 8:1}**

So if a value in the list is **4**, it needs to replace with **5** 
 If a value in the list is **2**, it needs to replace with **7** for each one.

when I try this code:

```
newList1 = list(map(int, newList))
nnList = []
for i in newList1:
    i = str(i).split(',')
    for y in list(map(str, i)):
        for n in y:
            print(n)
            if n == '1':
                n = 8
            elif n == '2':
                n = 7
            elif n == '6':
                n = 3
            elif n == '3':
                n = 6
            elif n == '4':
                n = 5
            elif n == '5':
                n = 4
            elif n == '7':
                n = 2
            elif n == '8':
                n = 1
            nnList.append(n)
print(nnList)
```

When I run this code, I have this output: **[7, 5, 5, 7, 1, 6, 7, 5, 3, 6, 8]** 
But I need to get in this way: **[7, 55, 71, 67, 53, 68]**

How can I do it?

Comment: Why is the expected output not `[7, 44, 28, 32, 46, 31]`?

Comment: @timgeb It looks like it's doing a digit-by-digit substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
newList = [2, 44, 28, 32, 46, 31]

d = {1:8, 2:7, 3:6, 4:5, 5:4, 6:3, 7:2, 8:1}

l = [int(''.join([str(d[int(g)]) for g in str(n)])) for n in newList]

print(l)
```

Output:

```
[7, 55, 71, 67, 53, 68]
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: you need to combine the new digits for a number into a single value before adding it to your list.

The longer answer is that you are doing far too many conversions. You don't need to convert the entire list of `int` values to a single string, and `newList` is already a list of `int` values; you don't need to build `newList1`.

```
nnList = []
for i in newList:
    newNum = int(''.join(str(9-int(x)) for x in str(i)))
    nnList.append(newNum)
```

Comment: This will produce wrong results if the OP changes any of the if-conditions

Comment: You can replace `9 - x` with `somedict[x]` as necessary. The giant `if` statement is a bit of a red herring; it has nothing to do with the actual problem, which was the failure to rejoin the digits of a number back into a new number.

Answer (score 0):

A more basic approach using `if else` and `looping` can be,

```
l1= [2, 44, 28, 32, 46, 31]
dict1={1:8, 2:7, 3:6, 4:5, 5:4, 6:3, 7:2, 8:1}
l2=[]
for n,i in enumerate(l1):
    str1=str(i)
    if len(str1)>1:
        str2=""

        for j in str1:

            if int(j) in dict1:
                str2+=str(dict1[int(j)])

                l1[n]=int(str2)
    else:
        if i in dict1:
            l1[n]=dict1[i]
print(l1)
```

output:

```
[7, 55, 71, 67, 53, 68]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
newlist = [2, 44, 28, 32, 46, 31]
repl = {1:8, 2:7, 3:6, 4:5, 5:4, 6:3, 7:2, 8:1}

for i, el in enumerate(newlist):
    newlist[i] = repl.get(el, newlist[i])

print(newlist)
```

`repl.get(el, newlist[1])` means: try to find `el` in the `repl` dictionary, if it is not in the dictionary, use `newlist[i]` (the original value) instead, thus replacing the value by itself.